# Universal App: Open Twitter application from my app

Tags: c#, xaml, twitter, win-universal-app

How do I make my Universal Application launch an another application like Twitter?

For example, opening Twitter and make it show a given profile (@somebody).

Answer (score 0):

I came across this webpage while trying to launch an external windows store app through a webpage.

This was very handy to get it done.

https://comentsys.wordpress.com/2015/05/13/windows-10-universal-windows-platform-web-browser/